# Converting JSONArray to XML in JSONSupport

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

- Does WSO2 ESB support converting JSONArray Payloads to XML ? (JSONArray at the root)

eg :

[
    {
        "a": 1,
        "b": 2,
        "value": 40,
        "string_val":"aa",
        "nullElement":null,
        "booleanElement":true
    },
    {
        "a": 4,
        "b": 5,
        "value": 35,
        "string_val":"bb",
        "booleanElement":false
    }
]

- Are you using any standard library in converting JSON to XML or using your own implementation? If so, what is the library you are using?

Thanks,
Joes

Answer (score 1):

WSO2 ESB (4.8.0) supports converting JSON arrays to XML. It uses StAXON to process JSON.